# Split a string using white space java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have a String like the following `2 4 12 12 yellow Hi how are you`

I want to split the string like this `{2,2,12,12,yellow, Hi how are you}` in order to pass the items in the list as parameters in a constructor.

Any help?

Comment: Well, `String.split`. But it's not obvious why `Hi how are you` should be a single string.

Comment: I know String.split(" "), but I need to store it in an array list like this way because I have a Note class where 2 and 4 represents x and y coordinates, 12 and 12 represents width and height, yellow represents color and hi how are you represent a message. When I create a new Note class it should be like this Note note = new Note(x,y,width,height,color,message); and then add it to an array list

Comment: `split(" ")` isn't the only way to split a string. Perhaps take a look at the documentation of `String` to see alternative ways.

Comment: I figured it out. I used split(" ", 6) which means limit on the 6 whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trivial answer is to split the string:

```
String[] fragments = theString.split(" ", 6);
```

Given that the fragments have specific meanings (and presumably you want some of them as non-string types), it might be more readable to use a `Scanner`:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(theString);
int x = sc.nextInt();
int y = sc.nextInt();
int width = sc.nextInt();
int height = sc.nextInt();
String color = sc.next();
String message = sc.nextLine();
```

This approach is also easier if you are reading these strings, say, from a file or standard input: just create the `Scanner` over the FileReader/InputStream instead.